# Android:XML different look with other android versions

Tags: android, xml, version

I have one app which get some coordinates and send it to google maps.
But I have one problem with the XML file.

When I change the android version 2.2 to 4 from the XML,the look get change and become different from the old one.

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks in advance.

Here is some pics:

Android 2.2

[image: http://i1305.photobucket.com/albums/s552/Mitko_Qnakiev/22_zps064a9f55.jpg]

Android 4.2.2

[image]

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical" >


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="138dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:prompt="@string/polus1" />


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="138dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
    android:layout_marginTop="-50dp" 
    android:prompt="@string/polus1" />



<TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvcords"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_gravity="center" 
      android:text="             №1  №2     №3          №4    №5     №6 "
      android:textSize="13dp" />

<TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvcords"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_gravity="center" 
      android:text="Example:45    7   25.87 N 123    6   48.97 W"
      android:textSize="16dp" /> 



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvcords"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="     Degrees"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" 
    android:textSize="14dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etcords"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:hint="    №1   " />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvcords1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="-65dp" 
    android:text="Minutes" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etcords1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:hint="    №2    "  />



 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvcords2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="-65dp" 
    android:text="Seconds      " />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etcords2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:hint="    №3    " />


 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvcords3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:text="     Degrees" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etcords3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:hint="    №4    "/>


 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvcords4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="-65dp"
    android:text="Minutes" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etcords4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:hint="    №5    "/>


 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvcords5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-65dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="Seconds      "  />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etcords5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:hint="    №6    " />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/bCount1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:textSize="20dp" />


 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResults"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp" 
    android:text="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The background of widgets are api level dependent.
So in order to have same look and feel in all versions you have to design them according to your needs and set the background attribute accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider version specific layouts, or alternatively you can try to craft a theme which looks ok on both versions. Another alternative is to use ActionBarSherlock and one of it's holo themes.